# How to convert a list to a dictionary AND add random value for the key

Tags: python

I'm sure I worded the question weird but bear with me...

Here is a sample of code I wrote

```
players = []
choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

for i in range(1, number_of_players + 1):
  players.append("P" + str(i))
  players_dictionary = dict.fromkeys(players, random.choice(choices))
```

If the number of players is, for example, 5, it will output

```
{ 'P1': 'Rock', 'P2': 'Rock', 'P3': 'Rock', 'P4': 'Rock', 'P5': 'Rock' }
```

I don't want each key to be the same, I want them to be randomized from the choices list. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following, using dict comprehension?

```py
import random

choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

d = {f'P{p+1}': random.choice(choices) for p in range(5)}
print(d) # {'P1': 'Paper', 'P2': 'Rock', 'P3': 'Scissors', 'P4': 'Paper', 'P5': 'Scissors'}
```

In your code, `dict.fromkeys` is the culprit. The [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) about `fromkeys` says:

> All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much. I am just now learning dictionaries and such so this gives me some insight as to how they work haha